# Connecting OPA to existing relational databases

Tags: opa

Is there any way to connect [OPA](http://opalang.org/) to existing data in relational databases (e.g. oracle or sql server)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is no. Here's my evidence:

http://opalang.org/jobs.xmlt

Scroll down to "Adding support for relational databases in Opa".

So it's not supported now, but the developers have it on their radar.

Comment: Yup, indeed, that's a pretty accurate summary. Although note that it's very easy to connect to existing REST APIs so of you have (or can set up) such a layer for your relational database that should work.